# Anaconda Pymc Install

Tags: anaconda, pymc

When attempting to install pymc via conda, I receive the following:

C:\Anaconda>conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/pymc pymc
Fetching package metadata: ...
Error: No packages found matching: pymc

The install is from the pymc distribution page: https://binstar.org/pymc/pymc

My current version of anaconda is up to date:

C:\Anaconda>conda update --prefix C:\Anaconda anaconda
Fetching package metadata: ..
Solving package specifications: .# All requested packages already installed.

# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda:

#

anaconda                  1.9.2                np18py27_0

So as a conda newbie, I'm not quite sure what I'm missing.  Perhaps I have to authorize binstar first?   (No proxy issues I believe.)

Much appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: How was this finally resolved. There still doesn't seem to be a win-64 version at binstar. So is there another source? Did you build it yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That build of pymc is only built for OS X 64-bit, Windows 32-bit, and Linux 64-bit (see https://binstar.org/pymc/pymc/2.3.2/files). I'm guessing you have Windows 64-bit. You should contact the pymc devs to see if they can build a 32-bit Windows version.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
!conda install pymc --yes
```

It should work. The `--yes` here used to skip a pause.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install an unofficial version for Windows 64-bit from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/